# How to start and debug opennms using Eclipse

Tags: opennms

I'm new with opennms. And I'm working in EMS development.
My team plan to move from current EMS to opennms.
I was successfully configure it using Eclipse but don't know how to start opennms and debug from Eclipse.

Actually, I have succeeded compile and assemble using the command /compile.sh and assemble.sh
But I need to know how to debug, compile and start the opennms using Eclipse.

Thanks,
Alya

Answer (score 1):

To start OpenNMS you have to use the "opennms script". This is located in `${opennms.home}/bin`

With the script you can then tell OpenNMS to run in debug mode, like so:
 `sudo ./opennms -t start`

OpenNMS then tells you what the remote debugger port is (default is: 8001).

In eclipse you can then "remote debug" OpenNMS. 
How to do this, you can e.g. follow this instruction (http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html)

I usually start opennms in verbose and debug mode : `sudo ./opennms -vt start`

**opennms usage**

```
Usage: ./opennms [-n] [-t] [-p] [-o] [-c timeout] [-v] [-Q] <command> [<service>]

command options: start|stop|restart|status|check|pause|resume|kill
service options: all|<a service id from the etc/service-configuration.xml>
defaults to all

The following options are available:

  -n  "No execute" mode.  Don't call Java to do anything.
  -t  Test mode.  Enable JPDA on port 8001.
  -p  Enable TIJMP profiling
  -o  Enable OProfile profiling
  -c  Controller HTTP connection timeout in seconds.
  -v  Verbose mode.  When used with the "status" command, gives the
      results for all OpenNMS services.  When used with "start", enables
      some verbose debugging, such as details on garbage collection.
  -Q  Quick mode.  Don't wait for OpenNMS to startup.  Useful if you
      want to watch the logs while OpenNMS starts up without wanting to
      open another terminal window.
```

**"opennnms script" examples**

- To start opennms: `sudo ./opennms start`
- To start opennms in verbose mode: `sudo ./opennms -v start`
- To start opennms in verbose and debug mode: `sudo ./opennms -vt start`
- To stop opennms: `sudo ./opennms stop`

Assuming you are in folder `${opennms.home}/bin`